# Displaying selected items in one jlist to another in java

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am using 4 `JList`s that is an array,

```
JList jlst = new JList[4];
```

Then I am adding first list items from array of objects,

```
jlst[0].setListData(getObjAL());
```

Here the function `getObjAL()` function will give the array of objects.

I want to display selected item of first list(`jlst[0]`) into second list(`jlst[1]`).

For that I am writing the code,

```
jlstPrimitives[i].addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listevt) {
        Jlist objLstTemp = (Jlist) listevt.getSource();
        jlst[1].setListData(objLstTemp.getSelectedValue()));
    }
});
```

But it is not displaying in `list[1]`.
Please any one help me...

Comment: Did you add the listener to the correct JList? The index should be "0". Did you add debug code to your listener to see it is invoked? How does your code compile? getSelectedValue() returns a single element. setListData() needs a Vector. YOu create your array with a name of "jlst" but then you add listeners to "jlstPrimitives". Where did that variable come from? The posted code is too confusing to be of much help. You need to post an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a dozen things that might be going wrong, none of which would affect you.  For better support in the future, post a runnable example that demonstrates your problem.  Pasting code out of context doesn't help (alot).

From your code, `getObjAL()` seems to be returning a `Object[]` array (single dimension), yet when you select a value, you seem to be assuming that the selected value is actually an array, which I'm pretty sure it isn't.

`JList#setListData` is expected either a object array (`Object[]`) or `Vector`.

Try something like this instead.

```
jlstPrimitives[i].addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listevt) {
        Jlist objLstTemp = (Jlist) listevt.getSource();
        jlst[1].setListData(new Object[]{objLstTemp.getSelectedValue()}));
    }
});
```